# add legends for combined 3 figures

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I would like to add same legend for my 3 figures.

Normally, I tend to use `ggarrange` or `plot_grid` function asking `common.legend = TRUE` to plot same legend. But now I want to add my legend that is same row with a single plot.

I want to have a figure as below.

Any sugesstions for me?
[image]

Link image: (http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/32-r-graphics-essentials/126-combine-multiple-ggplots-in-one-graph/)

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68448580/12957340 ?

Comment: Isn't this `library(patchwork);bxp + dp + lp + guide_area() + 
   plot_layout(guides = "collect")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a fairly easy way using base R graphic functionalities. Initialize a `plot.new()` and customize any `legend`.

```
cols <-  c(7, 4, 2)  ## colors


op <- par(mfrow=c(2, 2), mar=c(4.5, 4, 2, 2) + .1)  ## set and stor old pars

boxplot(len ~ dose, m, col=0, border=cols)
plot(len ~ jitter(dose), m, col=cols)
plot(m$len, type='l', col='orange')
plot.new()
legend('center', leg=c('foo', 'bar', 'baz'), pch=15, col=cols, h=TRUE, bty='n')

par(op)  ## restore old pars
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
m <- expand.grid(dose=c(.5, 1, 2), len=matrix(runif(100, 0, 30)))
m[, 2] <- m[, 2] + (1:3*10)
```

Comment: Question is about ggplot, in the comments twice they mentioned the solutions work from the links, why re-open?

Comment: @zx8754 Objection, OP in comment also seems very open to solutions other than ggplot2 => reopen. Hope it doesn't hurt too much:)

Answer (score -1):

We may also use `patchwork` (the objects 'bxp', 'dp', 'lp') created from the [link](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/32-r-graphics-essentials/126-combine-multiple-ggplots-in-one-graph/)

```
library(patchwork)
bxp + dp + lp + guide_area() +  
      plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

-output

[image]